# Why is nothing moving in this python script?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I copied this code from a python book, and the code is meant to be like an egg catcher game, however if you run the code, you can see, tkinter creates everything and the game sets up, however, the game itself does not start. Does anyone know how to make it start? I tried pressing buttons and making the whole thing a function, however, they both do not work. Here is my code below...

```
from itertools import cycle
from random import randrange
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk, messagebox, font

canvas_width = 800
canvas_height = 400

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background='deep sky blue')
c.create_rectangle(-5, canvas_height - 100, canvas_width + 5, canvas_height + 5, \
                    fill='sea green', width=0)
c.create_oval(-80, -80, 120, 120, fill='orange', width=0)
c.pack()
color_cycle = cycle(['light blue', 'light green', 'light pink', 'light yellow', 'light cyan'])
egg_width = 45
egg_height = 55
egg_score = 10
egg_speed = 500
egg_interval = 4000
difficulty_factor = 0.95
catcher_color = 'blue'
catcher_width = 100
catcher_height = 100
catcher_start_x = canvas_width / 2 - catcher_width / 2
catcher_start_y = canvas_height - catcher_height - 20
catcher_start_x2 = catcher_start_x + catcher_width
catcher_start_y2 = catcher_start_y + catcher_height

catcher = c.create_arc(catcher_start_x, catcher_start_y, \
 catcher_start_x2, catcher_start_y2, start=200, extent=140, \
 style='arc', outline=catcher_color, width=3)
game_font = font.nametofont('TkFixedFont')
game_font.config(size=18)
score = 0
score_text = c.create_text(10, 10, anchor='nw', font=game_font, fill='darkblue', \
 text='Score: ' + str(score))
lives_remaining = 3
lives_text = c.create_text(canvas_width - 10, 10, anchor='ne', font=game_font, fill='darkblue', \
 text='Lives: ' + str(lives_remaining))
eggs = []
def create_egg():
 x = randrange(10, 740)
 y = 40
 new_egg = c.create_oval(x, y, x + egg_width, y + egg_height, fill=next(color_cycle), width=0)
 eggs.append(new_egg)
 root.after(egg_interval, create_egg)
def move_eggs():
 for egg in eggs:
     (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
     c.move(egg, 0, 10)
     if egg_y2 > canvas_height:
         egg_dropped(egg)
         root.after(egg_speed, move_eggs)
def egg_dropped(egg):
 eggs.remove(egg)
 c.delete(egg)
 lose_a_life()
 if lives_remaining == 0:
     messagebox.showinfo('Game Over!', 'Final Score: ' + str(score))
     root.destroy()
def lose_a_life():
 global lives_remaining
 lives_remaining -= 1
 c.itemconfigure(lives_text, text='Lives: ' + str(lives_remaining))
def check_catch():
 (catcher_x, catcher_y, catcher_x2, catcher_y2) = c.coords(catcher)
 for egg in eggs:
     (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
     if catcher_x < egg_x and egg_x2 < catcher_x2 and catcher_y2 - egg_y2 < 40:
         eggs.remove(egg)
         c.delete(egg)
         increase_score(egg_score)
         root.after(100, check_catch)
def increase_score(points):
 global score, egg_speed, egg_interval
 score += points
 egg_speed = int(egg_speed * difficulty_factor)
 egg_interval = int(egg_interval * difficulty_factor)
 c.itemconfigure(score_text, text='Score: ' + str(score))
def move_left(event):
 (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
 if x1 > 0:
     c.move(catcher, -20, 0)
def move_right(event):
 (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
 if x2 < canvas_width:
     c.move(catcher, 20, 0)
     c.bind('<Left>', move_left)
     c.bind('<Right>', move_right)
     c.focus_set()
     root.after(1000, create_egg)
     root.after(1000, move_eggs)
     root.after(1000, check_catch)
     root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  IN particular, trace how you call the function that moves an element, the coordinates before and after, and that those new coordinates are still "safe" when you redraw the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see lots of functions but no calls to them, *especially* the function that runs the `Tkinter` main loop.

Given the similarity you would expect between the `move_left()` and `move_right()` functions, it's a near certainty that the final lines of the latter should *not* be indented to where they are.

With your *current* code, the lines doing the binding and timer call-back setups are only executed when `move_right()` is called. Which it isn't, because the key binding that would *call* it is only set up when it's called (which it isn't because ...

> `WARNING W-42: thought process terminated due to likely stack overflow in wet-ware` :-)

In other words, your code should be something like:

```
def move_left(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x1 > 0:
        c.move(catcher, -20, 0)

def move_right(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x2 < canvas_width:
        c.move(catcher, 20, 0)

# Run this at top level, NOT as part of move_right().

c.bind('<Left>', move_left)
c.bind('<Right>', move_right)
c.focus_set()
root.after(1000, create_egg)
root.after(1000, move_eggs)
root.after(1000, check_catch)
root.mainloop()
```

> As an aside, it may just be the way you pasted the code in, but you should try to follow the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide when writing code, specifically the four-space-indent guideline. They generally make your code much easier to read and/or analyse.

---

And, just so you're aware, those `move_xxx()` functions will actually allow your catcher to go off the edges of the screen (up to twenty pixels, I think). If that's *not* what you want, you may want to make a small change:

```
move_sz = 20

def move_left(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    c.move(catcher, -min(move_sz, x1), 0)

def move_right(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    c.move(catcher, min(move_sz, canvas_width - x2 - 1), 0)
```

I haven't tested that (particularly the possibility of being out by one pixel - I'll leave that up to you) but the idea is just to limit how much you move if that would send your catcher outside the canvas bounds.

You'll see I've also replaced the magic constant `20` with a more appropriate variable - that's so you only need to change it in one place should you want to adjust the movement speed.